# Get only those elements of array that match all elements of test array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

How can I get only the elements of the array that match all the elements of test array?, for instance, if I have:

```
>>> import numpy as np

>>> arr = np.array([[0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1]])
>>> arr == [0,0,1]
array([[ True,  True,  True],
   [False,  True,  True],
   [False,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

The solution for `arr == [0,0,1]` is the index `0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check the condition by row using an `axis` argument:

```
>>> (arr == np.array([0,0,1])).all(axis=1)
array([ True, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

If you want the index:

```
>>> np.where((arr == np.array([0,0,1])).all(axis=1))
(array([0]),)
```

We can also do something neat (and fast) to prevent calling `np.reduce` from `np.all`:

```
>>> b = np.array([0,0,1])
>>> dt = np.dtype((np.void, arr.dtype.itemsize * arr.shape[1]))
>>> (arr.view(dt) == b.view(dt)).reshape(-1)
array([ True, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

Some timings:

```
arr = np.random.randint(0,2,(1E2,3))

%timeit (arr.view(dt) == b.view(dt)).reshape(-1)
100000 loops, best of 3: 7.76 µs per loop
%timeit (arr == b).all(axis=1)
100000 loops, best of 3: 13.5 µs per loop
```

With larger arrays:

```
arr = np.random.randint(0,2,(1E5,3))

%timeit (arr.view(dt) == b.view(dt)).reshape(-1)
1 loops, best of 3: 221 ms per loop    
%timeit (arr == b)).all(axis=1)
1 loops, best of 3: 315 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
print arr[np.all((arr == [0,0,1]),axis=1)]
```

Or:

```
print np.arange(arr.shape[0])[np.all((arr == [0,0,1]),axis=1)]
```

if you want just the index of the answer

Comment: This only works, because it evaluates to false and therefore the 0 index. `arr[(arr == [1,0,1]).all()]` still gives the same result for example.

Comment: `.all` and `np.all` is the same function. the problem was not defining the axis.